# Using a server to run tasks with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, server, selenium-chromedriver

**Background**

I have built a chrome extension to run tasks automatically with python and selenium on my localhost.

I would like to use my extension on my smartphone (with a different network). For this, I just need to use a specific browser and its running well

---

**The Problem**

In order for my extension to work on a different device, I need a server to receive a request passing all the information to start the job.

The API is done, but I don't know how to proceed with the server part.

---

**What I've Tried**

- I tried to host on Heroku, it's working and I can receive requests, but *web-driver isn't working*. To being headless and the server is located in Europe, the website is blocking my access to the content.
- Also, I tried to use a proxy, but I need authentication, but that doesn't work with selenium.

---

**Further Explanation**

Basically, I need to enable my chrome extension to do a request directly to my personal computer or use a server with a graphical user interface to set-up the proxy manually, but I don't have any idea how to proceed with this or if that is even the best option.

Any thoughts about a good work around?

Comment: Please proofread your question before you upload it. That way, you will make your point better and more clearly.